# Resolving compiled default exports with ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, import, export, default

I have a module, say as follows:

```
const awesomeFn = () => ...

export default awesomeFn;
```

It is built into ES5 using babel, and when I created another ES6 module, I want the following syntax:

```
npm i awesomeFn

// ./index.js
import awesomeFn from 'awesomeFn';

awesomeFn();
```

But this throws. Logging `awesomeFn` gives me `{ default: _default [Function()] }` (or something like that), hinting that I'd need to do something like

```
import awesomeFnPackage from 'awesomeFn';
const { default: awesomeFn } = awesomeFnPackage;
```

How can I form my exports so that I don't have to do the default destructuring? Should I avoid default exports altogether for this reason?

---

Somewhat strangely, this works if:

- I use `esm`, like so `node -r esm index.js` but not if I use `mjs` as the file extension (with `"type": "module"` set), only `js`
- It doesn't work with `--experimental-modules`, `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` nor `"type": "module"` in `package.json`,
- In every non-working case, the import value is `{ default: [Function: awesomeFn] }`, only with `esm` is the value `[Function: awesomeFn]`

So I guess that's the solution right now; rely on an external package for expected behaviour, or use named exports, which do work as expected. What is going on with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided [here](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/444#issuecomment-785176894), which is to destructure the `default` property as stated in the question, or add [yet another dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) to intuitively use es6 imports.

I'll leave out the reasoning for why this choice was made by Babel to the reader to research for brevity. My conclusion is to use ES5 or not to use default exports. ES6 syntax is a mess in the context of import/exports as of writing, not only in the context of this question, but in the context of `npm` packaging, file extensions, flags, `package.json` properties, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Hei, it looks like a problem with your setup. Default functions are named "default" when exported (ES5).
You can probably destructure directly in the import statement like this:

```js
import { default as awesomeFn } from 'awesomeFn';

awesomeFn()
```

Comment: This doesn't work, default imports aren't "destructured"

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on what you meant by "it looks like a problem with your setup"? I agree that something seems wrong, I'm curious as to what that is

Comment: Ah, sorry. 

Bable should create this output: 

    `const awesomeFn = () => {
      console.log("hi");
    };

    var _default = awesomeFn;
    exports.default = _default;
`
In a es6 project it should fine to import the code like `import awesomeFn from  './awesomeFn';`

You can check your compiled code and see if it is similar.

Comment: Hey Ole, it does output something similar to that. I don't understand!